# Same update keeps showing up everyday

Tags: updates

I keep getting update of `numix-icons-theme` package everyday, how to stop it?

I've installed that update many times still it keeps showing up.

Comment: As you can see in the PPA https://launchpad.net/~numix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa the maintainers seem to update the packages a lot.

Comment: @xangua yes it makes sense

Answer (score 5):

First you should note this is dues to really another update every date as shown in their PPA. But if you still want not to get update from this repository you should use the "hold" concept to stop update from specific package.

You can do it using either `dpkg` or `apt`

#### Using dpkg

Put  hold on numix-icons-theme package

```
echo "numix-icons-theme hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Removing that hold

```
echo "numix-icons-theme install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

To check if hold is done run this:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "numix-icons-theme"
```

#### Using apt

Put  hold on numix-icons-theme package

```
sudo apt-mark hold numix-icons-theme
```

Removing that hold

```
sudo apt-mark unhold numix-icons-theme
```